# WARN rumen.TraceBuilder: No job found in traces

Tags: hadoop

I am using hadoop2.7.2 on ubuntu 16.04 LTS and developed a single node setup. I am running Rumen to create job traces from log history.

I am using following command:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoopjar/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-rumen-2.7.2.jar org.apache.hadoop.tools.rumen.TraceBuilder
file:///usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/sls/sample-data/job-trace.json 
file:///usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/sls/sample-data/job-topology.json
hdfs:///usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1486821591386_0001
```

But it throws an error "WARN rumen.TraceBuilder: no job found in traces" and same time it successfully create folders 'job-trace.json' and 'job-topology.json'. But job-trace.json is empty and job-topology.json has some values look like:

```
{    
  "name" : "root"    
  "children" : [ ]    
}
```

I don't know why is this happening. I have already searched everywhere but not getting anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem... I was giving wrong input path to Rumen. The actual path should be like this:

```
hdfs:///tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/history/done/2017/03/11/000000
```